# Finding the integral of a greatest integer

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate
>   $$\int_0^m\lfloor x\rfloor dx$$ 
>   where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer that is less than or equal to $x$, $m is a positive integer.

I know that Delta $x= 1$, width of each rectangle .
And height is $0,1,2,\dots, m-1$.
But I get stuck in between.
Can you please elaborate a bit more. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that for any integer $k$,  $\lfloor x\rfloor =k$ for ALL $x\in [k,k+1)$. Hence 
$$\int_0^m\lfloor x\rfloor dx=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\int_k^{k+1}\lfloor x\rfloor dx=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\int_k^{k+1}k dx.$$

Can you take it from here?